# Bug in Walrus operator

Tags: python, walrus-operator

I was working with the Walrus operator. I was getting the user to guess a number between 0 and 10. Their guess is then added to a list full of their guesses. But once they enter a 0, it just prints out the list.

The problem I am having is that the first guess doesn't get put in the list. I tried printing out the list every time a value was added, but the list just won't include the first input. How can I get the Walrus operator to append the first value to my list?

Here's my code:

```py
import traceback

def checkAnswerWalrus():
    listOfGuesses = []  

    while (numberGuessed := int(input(f"Guess a number between 0 to 10 : "))) != 0:
        listOfGuesses.append(numberGuessed)
        print(listOfGuesses)

    if numberGuessed == 0:
        print(listOfGuesses)

    return(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        numberGuessed = int(input(f"Guess a number between 0 to 10 : "))
        checkAnswerWalrus()
    except Exception as error:
        traceback.print_exc()

    finally:
        print(f":)")
```

Here's the example output, where the "2" isn't being appended to the list :

```
C:/Python3.8/python.exe c:/Users/mayab/Desktop/ict/python/misc/testWalrus.py
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 2
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 3
[3]
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 4
[3, 4]
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 5
[3, 4, 5]
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 6
[3, 4, 5, 6]
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 7
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Guess a number between 0 to 10 : 0
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
:)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly come to the conclusion there's a but in the operator. You simply have an extra line taking input an not processing it.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is asked and the first number input in the `try` section,  where you do not append the value to a list. Just remove it and let  `checkAnswerWalrus()` do the whole work.